# How to retrieve data from multiple collections mongo db laravel 5.4

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

Actually I want get data from two different Collections using join or $lookup method  but always getting empty result .

I am trying to get data by using Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model.

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried?

Comment: You can add relationship in model